# Parse request content json to object in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, post

I have controller in Laravel:

```
public function addUserTesterPost(Request $request)
{
    $requestContent = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    
    $emil = $requestContent->email; //error: $requestContent is null
   
}
```

this is json that I received in `$request->getContent()`:

```
{                     
  'email': 'dean',
  'psw': 'dean123',
}
```

How to parse above json to object to fetch email?
I send request from Postman, in header I have set `content-type: application/json`.

Comment: Try `$email = $request->email;`

Comment: In your code you are decoding the content into array, and you have to convert it to object using (object)json_decode(...);

Comment: `$request->email` doesn't work, in the second case, when I cast to object I have error: `ErrorException: Undefined property: stdClass::$email in file C:\xampp\htdocs\fff\app\Http\Controllers\UserApiController.php on line 41`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an **array** `json_decode($request->getContent(), true);`

The **->** cannot be used for array, instead use **[ ]** `$requestContent['email'];`

Comment: `$requestContent['email']` gives me null, how to check what object is returned from json_decode ?

Comment: `$requestContent[0]->email` is correct answer and the json should be taken in `[{...}]`

Answer (score 1):

A couple of observations:
For some reason, I had issue when setting the body content with single quotes, so if anyone has unknown issues, begin by changing the body (postman) data to double quotes:

```json
{                     
  "email": "dean",
  "psw": "dean123",
}
```

To retrieve the data in the controller, this worked for me:

```php
$email = $request->json()->all()['email'];
```